# parse Javascript src via php in order to eliminate unused branches

Tags: javascript, php, parsing

I am trying to work out how to have PHP read raw Javascript source code and remove redundant branch blocks, e.g.

```
function foo(a) {
    if ( true ) {
       console.log('experiment 1');
    }
    else {
       console.log('experiment 2');
    }
}
```

....needs to drop second console.log block and return ...

```
function foo(a) {
    if ( true ) {
       console.log('experiment 1');
    }
}
```

Is there anything out there already or do I need to investigate parsing the src?

Comment: Its not easy task, (1) parse code, (2) analysis it (3) emit result, Basically You need to write a compiler.

Comment: Beyond what @Nur said, how would you do the same for any other language, including PHP. I’d recommend looking into a library for this